# Access Denied Error when issuing Install-AzureWinRMCertificate

Tags: powershell, azure, microsoft-dynamics

I have been working diligently to get Dynamics Installed on Azure, I have made it a good way through the Example-1VM.ps1 before encountering a failure to ***'Install-AzureWinRMCertificate'*** error message indicating access denied.  The error is coming while running the PowerShell script **'New-NAVAdminSession.ps1'**  I can see from looking in Azure, much of the work has been done properly from the Example-1VM.ps1 file, but I'm not sure what is next,    Can I manually install the certificate and if so may I know how?  If not, how do I correct this so I can re-run the Example-1VM.ps1 script.

Comment: Do you try install it as administrator user?

Comment: I was using the PowerShell ISE and running it as Administrator, I will try this again, just in case.  Is there another way to specify that I am administrator user other than running ISE as admin?

Comment: You could open "PowerShell" `Run as Administrator`

Comment: Yes,  have done, so to no avail.

Comment: Well Walter, I must fall on my sword Mate, I tried again, I exited from PowerShell ISE session and re-entered selecting Administrator and this time the script went farther than before and it did install the certificates.  I must have simply exited and returned at some point and did not even notice.  My BAD!    Thank you push to double check.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Walter slapping me upside the head (kindly of course) to double check if I was running PowerShell ISE as Administrator I was able to get this resolved.

Once I exited PowerShell ISE and re-entered the desktop application with the option 'run as Administrator' all worked fine.

Just goes to show sometimes we are too close to our own problems.

Cheers Walter

Answer (score 0):

According to your error log, it seems a permission issue. Please close your PowerShell and run PowerShell `Run as Administrator`.